# Solving the equation $\frac {27^{2x}}{3^{5-x}} = \frac {3^{2x+1}}{9^{x+3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$\frac {27^{2x}}{3^{5-x}} = \frac {3^{2x+1}}{9^{x+3}}$$

I tried simplifying this way:

$$\frac {3^{6x}}{3^{5-x}} = \frac{3^{2x+1}}{3^{2x+6}}$$

but im not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{3^a}{3^b}=3^{a-b}$

Answer (score 0):

The final equality is equivalent to$$3^{7x-5}=3^{-5},$$which is equivalent to $x=0$.